# SQL Server : script automation help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012, and I have to automate some task (scripts). This task is a weekly task I am doing every Friday.

It consist of executing manually (pressing F5) a bunch of truncates and select + inserts. I can not show you the code because is sensitive and I would be fired if I would do that.

The idea I had is either to do a stored procedure on that and put that stored procedure in a SQL Job or maybe a SSIS package?

Could you please give me any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: a job sounds good, what other ideas do you need?

Comment: An SSIS package would still need a job so you can schedule it.

Comment: if you can do all your actions in a stored procedure, I would suggest creating a job where you put in the stored procedure.

Comment: You could just replace the table / column names in your SQL. Hardly there can be any secrets in your code... :)

Comment: another Idea a colleague had to do batch file.. could this be done? I will update with a code example